# Pass kernel boot parameters from dhcpd.conf for a host group?

Tags: boot, kernel, dhcpd

Is it possible to configure `dhcpd.conf` such that a specific host group would use an additional kernel boot parameter passed on to the kernel loading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not DHCP who can do this, but PXE.

An example (not necessarily useful for you) `dhcpd.conf` file:

```
allow booting;
allow bootp;
authoritative;
default-lease-time      600;
max-lease-time          7200;
option domain-name      "domain.com";
ddns-update-style       none;
log-facility            local7;
deny unknown-clients;
subnet 192.168.124.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  option routers               192.168.124.1;
  option subnet-mask           255.255.255.0;
  option domain-name-servers   199.245.70.156;
  filename                     "pxelinux.0";
  next-server                  192.168.124.81;
    host foo {
      hardware ethernet        f4:xx:46:xx:xx:67;
      fixed-address            192.168.124.25;
      option host-name         "foo";
    }
}
```

I have used a rule to match a specific MAC address, modify to match a group as needed.
The `next-server` and `filename` parameter tell the host requesting an IP (and matching the requirements) to boot using the `pxelinux.0` file, that can be found in `192.168.124.81`.

The TFTP server at that IP address will typically have a default configuration in the lines of:

```
default menu.c32
prompt 0

menu title PXE Boot Menu
menu include pxelinux.cfg/graphics.conf
menu autoboot Starting Local System in # seconds

label rhel6
  menu label Install - ^RHEL6 64
  kernel rhel/6/x86_64/vmlinuz
  initrd rhel/6/x86_64/initrd.img
  append ks=http://10.0.0.2/rhel6/ks/rhel6.cfg ksdevice=eth0
```

You can use the `append` parameter here to add any valid custom value to the kernel.